# Test dispatch called with correct obj inside handleChange method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to jest so I am struggling. I am using the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) package. When you select an item it triggers the handleChange method to be called with a selectedOption argument like `{value:'some value'}`. I want to test that dispatch is called within handleChange and that its called with the correct object.

here is the handleChange method

```
export class CustomerSelect extends React.Component {
      //other code

      handleChange = selectedOption => {
        const obj = {
          type: 'SET_CUSTOMER',
          payload: selectedOption.value
        };
        this.props.dispatch(obj);
      };

     //other code
}
```

here is my test code

```
let wrapper, instance, dispatch, customers;

beforeEach(() => {
  customers = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
  dispatch = jest.fn();
  wrapper = shallow(<CustomerSelect customers={customers} dispatch={dispatch} />);
  instance = wrapper.instance();
});


  test('fire off dispatch on change', () => {
    const handleChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleChange');
    instance.forceUpdate();
    const selectedOption = { value: customers[1] };
    const obj = {
        type: 'SET_CUSTOMER',
        payload: selectedOption.value
      };

    wrapper.find(Select).simulate('change', { selectedOption });

    //check handleChange was called
    expect(handleChangeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      selectedOption
    });

    //check dispatch was called
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);
  });
```

What's happening is that it's not picking up on the selectedOption as I get an error

```
  Object {
-   "payload": "test2",
+   "payload": undefined,
    "type": "SET_ACCOUNT",
  }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are sending wrong parameter, try that

```
wrapper.find(Select).simulate('change', selectedOption);

//check handleChange was called
expect(handleChangeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(selectedOption);
expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);
```